# Any issues if we disable locking for Cm RedisSession read?

Tags: magento-1.9

We had an issue whereby our pages took a long time to load. Upon dissecting the time taken by various layers to service the request on NewRelic, we found that the method `Cm_RedisSession_Model_Session::read` took around 30 seconds to complete.

That is also the default timeout to wait for the lock.

```
/* Try to break the lock after this many seconds */
const DEFAULT_BREAK_AFTER           = 30;
```

We look at the writes that take place once the lock is acquired, and it's more towards storing the PID and the request details.

```
    // This process has the lock, save the pid
    if ($this->_hasLock) {
        $setData = array(
            'pid' => $this->_getPid(),
            'lock' => 1,
        );

        // Save request data in session so if a lock is broken we can know which page it was for debugging
        if ($this->_logLevel >= Zend_Log::INFO) {
            if (empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
                $setData['req'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
            } else {
                $setData['req'] = "{$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']} {$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
            }
            if ($lock != 1) {
                $this->_log(sprintf(
                    "Successfully broke lock for ID %s after %.5f seconds (%d attempts). Lock: %d\nLast request of broken lock: %s",
                    $sessionId, (microtime(true) - $timeStart), $tries, $lock, $this->_redis->hGet($sessionId, 'req')
                ), Zend_Log::INFO);
            }
        }
        $this->_redis->hMSet($sessionId, $setData);
    }
```

Upon searching, we found several articles describing the same issue, and that one of the solutions is to simply disable the locking.

https://astrio.net/blog/redis-slow-session-magento/

https://willparsons.tech/redis-session-locking/

Our question is simply - would we encounter issues if we we're to disable locking for Cm RedisSession read?

Our setup consists of multiple, load balanced, auto-scalable Magento frontend nodes operating on a single Magento instance having multiple stores.

Comment: disable locking and see

Comment: Asking around before we do so to avoid any unforeseen issues, but yeah the gut feel is that everything's gonna be all right.